How To Make a cpi call to swap on raydium clmm program?
I worked out an program to make a swap cpi call to raydium v4 pool, with the help of raydium offically offered an cpi demo, raydium-contract-instructions.
But not found any resources or instruction to make a swap cpi call to raydium clmm.
Has anyone successed to make a cpi call before, pls help, thx

Which instruction would do you want to call?
Here are the docs https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-docs/blob/master/dev-resources/raydium-clmm-dev-doc.pdf
Raydium does provide CPI examples on how to do this in the CPI examples repo
Find CLMM examples here https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cpi-example/tree/master/clmm-cpi/programs/clmm-cpi
For example, here are the ix's for a SwapSingleV2
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::Token;
use anchor_spl::token_interface::{Mint, Token2022, TokenAccount};
use raydium_amm_v3::{
    cpi,
    program::AmmV3,
    states::{AmmConfig, ObservationState, PoolState},
};

/// Memo msg for swap
pub const SWAP_MEMO_MSG: &'static [u8] = b"raydium_swap";
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ProxySwap<'info> {
    pub clmm_program: Program<'info, AmmV3>,
    /// The user performing the swap
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// The factory state to read protocol fees
    #[account(address = pool_state.load()?.amm_config)]
    pub amm_config: Box<Account<'info, AmmConfig>>,

    /// The program account of the pool in which the swap will be performed
    #[account(mut)]
    pub pool_state: AccountLoader<'info, PoolState>,

    /// The user token account for input token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub input_token_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The user token account for output token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub output_token_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The vault token account for input token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub input_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The vault token account for output token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub output_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The program account for the most recent oracle observation
    #[account(mut, address = pool_state.load()?.observation_key)]
    pub observation_state: AccountLoader<'info, ObservationState>,

    /// SPL program for token transfers
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    /// SPL program 2022 for token transfers
    pub token_program_2022: Program<'info, Token2022>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
        address = spl_memo::id()
    )]
    pub memo_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// The mint of token vault 0
    #[account(
        address = input_vault.mint
    )]
    pub input_vault_mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,

    /// The mint of token vault 1
    #[account(
        address = output_vault.mint
    )]
    pub output_vault_mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,
    // remaining accounts
    // tickarray_bitmap_extension: must add account if need regardless the sequence
    // tick_array_account_1
    // tick_array_account_2
    // tick_array_account_...
}

pub fn proxy_swap<'a, 'b, 'c: 'info, 'info>(
    ctx: Context<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, ProxySwap<'info>>,
    amount: u64,
    other_amount_threshold: u64,
    sqrt_price_limit_x64: u128,
    is_base_input: bool,
) -> Result<()> {
    let cpi_accounts = cpi::accounts::SwapSingleV2 {
        payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        amm_config: ctx.accounts.amm_config.to_account_info(),
        pool_state: ctx.accounts.pool_state.to_account_info(),
        input_token_account: ctx.accounts.input_token_account.to_account_info(),
        output_token_account: ctx.accounts.output_token_account.to_account_info(),
        input_vault: ctx.accounts.input_vault.to_account_info(),
        output_vault: ctx.accounts.output_vault.to_account_info(),
        observation_state: ctx.accounts.observation_state.to_account_info(),
        token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        token_program_2022: ctx.accounts.token_program_2022.to_account_info(),
        memo_program: ctx.accounts.memo_program.to_account_info(),
        input_vault_mint: ctx.accounts.input_vault_mint.to_account_info(),
        output_vault_mint: ctx.accounts.output_vault_mint.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.clmm_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts)
        .with_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec());
    cpi::swap_v2(
        cpi_context,
        amount,
        other_amount_threshold,
        sqrt_price_limit_x64,
        is_base_input,
    )
}

